# Job is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, ejs

I'm trying to create an application form that an applicant can submit depending on what position he/she wants, however if i try to click submit on the application form, i'm getting the error as shown below. I don't know what to do, i thought i have everything figured out but i'm not sure where i missed. Please help, thank you in advance.

**router**

```
const Job = require('../../models/Job');

router.get("/jobs", function(req, res){
    Job.find()
        .then(results => {
            res.render('jobs/', { Job: results })
        })
        .catch(error => console.error(error))
});


//applicants handling
router.post("/jobs", function(req, res){
    const { applicant, email, contact, address, position} = req.body;
    let errors = [];

    if(!applicant || !email || !contact || !address || !position){
        errors.push({ msg: 'Please fill out all fields.' });
    }

    if(errors.length > 0 ){
        res.render('jobs/',{
            errors,
            applicant,
            email,
            contact,
            address,
            position
        });
    }else{
        Applicants.findOne({applicant: applicant})
            .then(user => {
                if(user){
                    errors.push({ msg: 'You already sent an application, no worries we will get back at you soon.' })
                    res.render('jobs/',{
                        errors,
                        applicant,
                        email,
                        contact,
                        address,
                        position
                    });
                }else{
                    const newApplicants = new Applicants({
                        applicant,
                        info:{
                            email,
                            contact,
                            address,
                        },
                        position:{
                            position
                        }
                    });

                    newApplicants.save()
                    errors.push({ msg: 'Thank you for sending as a application notice, we will contact you soon.' })
                }
            });
    }
});
```

**views/jobs/index.ejs**

```
...
<% for(var i=0; i < Job.length; i++) { %>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title"><%= Job[i].title %></h5>
      <p class="card-text"><%= Job[i].description %></p>
      <div class="text-muted mb-4">Requirements: <%= Job[i].requirements %></div>
      <p>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#<%= Job[i].title%>" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
          Apply Now
        </a>
      </p>
      <div class="collapse" id="<%= Job[i].title %>">
        <div class="card card-body">
          <%- include('../_partial/messages') -%>

          <h4>Applying for <%= Job[i].title %></h4>
          <form action="/jobs" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Full Name</label>
              <input
                type="text" 
                class="form-control" 
                id="applicant" 
                name="applicant"
                value="<%- typeof applicant != 'undefined' ? applicant: '' -%>"
              >
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email Address</label>
              <input
                type="email" 
                class="form-control" 
                id="description" 
                name="description"
                value="<%- typeof description != 'undefined' ? description: '' -%>"
              >
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Contact Number</label>
              <input
                type="text" 
                class="form-control" 
                id="contact" 
                name="contact"
                value="<%- typeof contact != 'undefined' ? contact: '' -%>"
              >
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Complete Address</label>
              <input
                type="text" 
                class="form-control" 
                id="address" 
                name="address"
                value="<%- typeof address != 'undefined' ? address: '' -%>"
              >
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input
                type="hidden" 
                id="position" 
                name="position"
                value="<%= Job[i].title %>"
              >
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit Application Form</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <%if (i > 0) { %>
    </div>
    <% } %>
  <% } %>
...
```

**Error**

```
ReferenceError: /home/redacted/Projects/redacted/views/jobs/index.ejs:12
    10| </div>
    11| <div class="container mb-5">
 >> 12|   <% for(var i=0; i < Job.length; i++) { %>
    13|   <div class="card">
    14|     <h5 class="card-header">Urgent</h5>
    15|     <div class="card-body">

Job is not defined
...
```

Comment: The error is on the POST route right? I don't see you sending `Job` on the POST route, only on the GET route.

Comment: yeah i think so but there's a router.post for handling the data from forms and router.get to provide the Job.title

Comment: Job is not a JS variable, it is a EJS variable so try `<% for(var i=0; I < <%=Job.length%>; i++) { %>`

Comment: @NithinKJoy hahaha that doesn't work at all theres no way <% for(var i=0; I < <%=Job.length%> that's an invalid syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the error:

```
ReferenceError: /home/redacted/Projects/redacted/views/jobs/index.ejs:12
    10| </div>
    11| <div class="container mb-5">
 >> 12|   <% for(var i=0; i < Job.length; i++) { %>
```

You have written an EJS template that requires a rendering variable `Job` to exist.

The simplest way to guard against this kind of error is to add some code at the top of your EJS template such as:

```
<%
locals.Job = locals.Job || [];
%>
```

This is called null coalescing and means we are supplying a default value for `Job` if none was provided. The `locals` variable is used by EJS to hold the render data you normally pass in as the second parameter to the render function, eg.:

```
// In this example, locals = { Job: results };
res.render('jobs/', { Job: results })
```

We don't usually have to explicitly write `locals.Job` and can generally use just `Job` within the EJS template file, except in the case where it has not previously been defined.

In your example, it is explicitly this case which is causing the error:

```
res.render('jobs/',{
    errors,
    applicant,
    email,
    contact,
    address,
    position
});
```

As you can see, the second parameter does not contain a `Job` key.